# How can I install ubuntu 12.10 with a UEFI boot (win8, without DVD driver)?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

Dual boot. I tried with a bootable USB, but my computer still went straight to Windows 8. Then I followed the instruction on its website, tried with a windows-installer http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows 
But still unable to load Ubuntu, \Ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

Is there any way I could load Ubuntu correctly? I think something is wrong with my windows boot manager or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

WUBI is incompatible with UEFI, so don't bother trying it on an EFI/UEFI-based system.

Check your manual to learn how to enter the firmware setup utility or to get the firmware's built-in boot manager. Using the former, you should be able to adjust the boot order to boot from a USB device before booting from the hard disk; or using the latter, you should be able to boot from a USB device first on a one-time basis. Unfortunately, the details of how to enter the firmware setup utility and the firmware boot manager vary from one implementation to another, so I can't say precisely how to do this. On most computers, it's a matter of pressing Del or a function key at a critical point during the boot process. Some systems eliminate or hide this option in favor of a Windows-based interface, though. I don't recall exactly where the option to adjust EFI settings within Windows is, but perhaps a Web search would turn up the answer.